# SSH Permission denied on reboot

Tags: git, github, ssh

I created a repo at home two days ago and did some work on it, then yesterday set up my SSH key at work so I can push to that repo and it worked fine.
However today, I am getting permission denied message, as if my SSH key is no longer linked.
It is stored locally, and I can also still see it in my github settings. 
What could cause this?
OS: Antergos Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the key is stored in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

With an encrypted home, you can not log in with the key as your home directory is encrytped.

Move authorized keys to somewhere else, I personally use `/etc/ssh/.authorized_keys`

You then edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` , add/edit the line

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/.authorized_keys
```

Restart ssh server.

You can also Refer to :

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html

Comment: So yesterday I moved the files, and added the key to the agent again due to it's new location and it worked. 
However upon reboot this morning, the issue still occurs where permission is denied.

Comment: There is something that is encrypting your home directory, Try to contact to Your NOC Team that you are getting this message & Also why don't you get `root` access to the server ?

Comment: This is a personal laptop, with an encrypted home which I use for work. connection to enterprise github is totally fine, just github.com is not

Comment: It appears the key is getting reset from the agent. I have added it again and will update with how it persists through reboot.

Comment: @Fenwick17, I believe now it's a different issue you are looking for. What I have answered solves the issue, as I faced it myself. Also keep habit of upvoting the answers or questions which you find helpful. It will encourgage both asker and answerer.

Comment: thanks, I have updated the issue as solved. As ive moved onto another issue which I can temporarily resolve by telling bash profile to just add the key. 
Thanks for the help

Comment: @Fenwick17, Most welcome Bro. Hope you solve it soon !